# Is Restful independent of the transport protocol?

Tags: rest, soap

I am doing a test, and I am confused on the below question

Which two statements are true about RESTful web services?

A.  They can be both stateful and stateless.

B.  They support the use of AJAX in web applications.

C.  They are often similar than their Simple Object Access protocol (SOAP) equivalents.

D.  They are independent of the transport protocol.

E.  They support Remote Procedure Call (RPC) and message-Oriented Middleware (MOM) integration styles.

There are some test that it answers B & C and other that it answers B & D.
What is the correct answers?

Answer (score 1):

The option C. has a typo: 'similar' shall be 'simpler'.

Correct answer is B and C.

A. is wrong. REST is stateless. RESTful web service can be made stateful, by sending back and forth a session-id, same goes with SOAP web service. However, REST concept is to use the HTTP infrastructure and be super scalable. Once there is a state maintained, then scalability suffers as one can not reuse the same URL to serve any (other client’s) request

D. is wrong as SOAP web service can support many transport protocols but not REST.

E. is wrong. This is a feature for SOAP web services.